# Ambari cluster setup without Cloudera subscription

Tags: ambari

After Cloudera-Hortonworks merging, it seems that the setup of a HDP cluster requires a Cloudera subscription (i.e., https://archive.cloudera.com/p/HDP/ubuntu18/3.x/updates/3.1.5.0/HDP-3.1.5.0-152.xml is not accessible)

Is it possible to setup an Ambari cluster with free version Version Definition Files?

Answer (score 1):

@mauro-scarpa You can setup Ambari Cluster with free versions.  You just have to go to HDP 3.1.4.  Going forward, new versions are behind the paywall.